# Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F; I can not burn bootloader on my arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, usbasp

well...
the problem starts from the time that I accidentally touched the crystal on my arduino and all of a sudden everything messed up; the leds on arduino turned on and off while being touched, and after that I was unable to program it...
after a lot of searches, I decided t burn bootloader again...
so I got a USBasp and wired it to arduino and tried to program it using programmer or burning bootloader...
but...
It is not posible because of the following ERROR:

```
**Arduino: 1.8.15 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.

avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F

         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

Error while burning bootloader.**
```

I tried changing that 0xF in config file to 0x14, because of the difference between ATmega328 and ATmega328p...
but still no progress...
I will be very glad if someone can help me run this UNO...

by the way, is it possible that the crystal which I touched with hand is ruined or interrupted and all of these stuff is because of that?

Comment: What crystal? Is it a genuine Arduino or a cheap Chinese POS?

Comment: its a 16mHz smd crystal...

Comment: and I dont think it to be chinese...

Comment: The crystal by the ATMega328P chip or the crystal by the USB interface chip?

Comment: the one by the ATmega

Comment: Then if it's a real Arduino it's not a crystal but a ceramic resonator. But there's always a chance you zapped the chip with static. Did you feel a shock when you touched it?

Comment: no, nothing like a zap...just sth like a touch screen that when I touch it, things change like leds

Comment: Any chance you could take a short video?

Comment: Or upload it to google photos and share the link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u4wfHMXPAMI16Mm7IDgOGQIH4MAds16J/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, so it's not a genuine Arduino. It's just the TX and L LEDs that light up. The L could be being controlled by a sketch that is triggered from a floating input. The TX LED is connected to the CH340G chip and no one really know what goes on with those things.

Comment: I was thinking that there must be sth wrong with fuse bits and boot loader...so, reprograming it should have worked, but well...it is not working...any suggestion?

Comment: It's more likely the CH340G chip has died. They're known to be very sensitive.

Comment: thats really a bad news...but anyhow...thanks for the time you put on this...I do appriciate it... ;)

Comment: You could try a "loopback" test to see if the USB interface is working or not.  1. Connect RESET to GND. 2. Connect pin 0 to pin 1. 3. Connect the Arduino to the PC. 4. Open the serial monitor in the IDE with the right port selected. 5. Type something. You should see what you type echoed back to you.

Comment: well...I did as you said...nothing happens...i an not see the message I type in response...it fade...and when I press ENTER, for a moment RX and TX leds on arduino blink...just this...

Comment: It sounds like the CH340G may be dead then. You can try using an external USB to UART adapter connected to the TX/RX pins and bypass the CH340G to keep using your board. Treat it like a "breadboard arduino" but with the chip still on the PCB.

Comment: I would use it for a mechanical template and purchase a new one. At this point we do not know what all failed. If you have the time and skill set go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well a couple of options:

- Plug the Arduino with USB, do you see a Serial PORT? If you do there is a good chance the USB CHIP is ok.
- Try programming the Arduino with a 12v High Voltage Programmer and burn a 8Mhz Internal oscillator bootloader and see if it works, if it does, the the crystal is damaged.
- Another alternative, e to use a 16mhz crystal and put it in parallel with that one, see if you can flash it like that, or just desolder that one and replace with a new one, doesn't matter if it's the same freq, you still be able to burn a bootloader, hopefully choose a osc that is supported by the bootloaders (8, 12, 16, 20) for example